# Efficiently converting pandas dataframe to scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert a pandas Dataframe to a scipy sparse matrix as a way to efficiently work with many features.

However I didn't find an efficient way to access the values in the dataframe, so I always run out of memory when doing the conversion. I tried the two solutions below and they just don't work. I've researched a lot but didn't find anything better. If anyone has a suggestion I'd be happy to test it.

```
sparse_array = sparse.csc_matrix(df.values)
sparse_array = sparse.csc_matrix(df.to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is very sparse you could convert it column-wise and then stack:

```
from scipy import sparse

sparse_array = sparse.hstack([sparse.csc_matrix(df[i].values.reshape(-1, 1)) for i in df.columns])
```

But probably best is to just turn it into a sparse dataframe:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = df[i].astype(pd.SparseDtype(df[i].dtype))

sparse_array = sparse.csc_matrix(df.sparse.to_coo())
```

(Note that there may be an issue if your dtypes are not homogeneous throughout the dataframe).

Comment: Hey CJR thanks for the reply. I tested here and indeed seems that it worked. When you mentioned not homogeneous you mean that I can have an issue if I have floats and integers, for example? If yes, what sort of issue could I have?

Comment: If you're keeping it as a sparse dataframe there's no issue - the scipy sparse matrix is a single dtype though. If you have floats and ints, one will have to turn into the other if you want a matrix. (If you have a column of strings, even worse - now it's a matrix of python objects, but it'll probably crash so good news there)